# Cmder - Use <tab> to cycle through the auto completes candidates?

Tags: cmder

In the original cmd.exe in Windows,  can be used to cycle through the auto completes candidates. But in cmder, this feature seems to be removed. Is there anyway to enable it?

Comment: Why do you trying cmder instead of official [ConEmu](http://conemu.github.io/) than?

Comment: @Maximus Just came across cmder and never tried others... Thanks!

Comment: cmder is just a **preconfigured** ConEmu with some **third-party** software

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As mentioned above, '**cmder**' is an amalgamation of other open source software. The software which controls the tab completion behaviour is '**clink**'. To change this behaviour, navigate to your '**cmder**' directory and then find:

*\cmder\vendor\clink\clink_inputrc_base*

Open 'clink_inputrc_base', save a backup original, and then replace both lines that read:

*"\t":               clink-completion-shim*

with:

*"\t":               menu-complete*

for shift+tab cycle backward behaviour, also add a line below each of the above lines that reads:

*"\e`Z":             menu-complete-backward*

This worked for me. Credit to this link for the info on modifying clink behaviour:

https://github.com/mridgers/clink/issues/190

**EDIT: Please see my comment below, or additional answer from 'tides'. In newer versions of cmder the process is slightly simpler. You just have to uncomment the lines as described in the file, see my comment or other answer for more detail.**

Comment: UPDATE: I just downloaded a newer version of cmder (v1.3.6) and now the file above has two lines commented, above which it says "# Uncomment these two lines for vanilla cmd.exe style completion." If you uncomment the two lines below it will achieve the same behaviour as my answer here.

Comment: Will it be possible to make <tab> works as: 1st <tab> -- list all possible commands, 2nd and after <tab> -- completion?

Comment: Instead of modifying clink_inputrc_base you can just place a .inputrc file to %USERPROFILE% folder that modifies "\t" and "\e`Z".

Answer (score 13):

Actually, in the `\cmder\vendor\clink\clink_inputrc_base` file there are already these lines at the end:

```
# Uncomment these two lines for vanilla cmd.exe style completion.
# "\t": clink-menu-completion-shim
# "\e`Z": clink-backward-menu-completion-shim
```

If you remove the `#` characters of the last two lines you will get the desired behavior.

Comment: Thanks, yes noted this in my comments on 22nd June. This wasn't present in earlier versions of cmder.

Comment: Anyway to exclude items that are not actually in the current working directory?

Comment: Still doesn't autocomplete for the `git` command

Answer (score 2):

Clink changes Tab completion behavior. So: remove clink from `vendors` folder, uncheck [Use clink in prompt](https://conemu.github.io/en/SettingsFeatures.html#id2418).

Comment: It works after I remove clink, though I didn't check `Use clink in prompt` at first place. One more problem is that now `{lamb}` and `{git}{hg}` appears. Git prompt seems to break when I cd to a git dir.

Comment: Install official ConEmu and configure it for your taste

Comment: @Maximus how? can you expand

Answer (score 0):

The previous answers did not work for me. Here is how I got it to work, looking at [Clink documentation](https://chrisant996.github.io/clink/clink.html) and something from [this post](https://brettterpstra.com/2011/09/25/quick-tip-some-inputrc-fun/). First, instead of editing any base configuration file (which will probably be overwritten on updates anyway), create your own configuration file, which you can call `.inputrc` or `_inputrc`, in one of the following locations:

- `%CLINK_INPUTRC%`
- `%USERPROFILE%`
- `%LOCALAPPDATA%`
- `%APPDATA%`
- `%HOME%`

Probably the most practical thing in most cases is to create it in your home directory (e.g. `C:\Users\My Name\`).

Inside that file, write the following content:

```
TAB: menu-complete
"\e[Z": menu-complete-backward
```

And that's it. It's still not exactly what I wanted, as I'd prefer it would show me the list of possible completions the first time I hit `TAB` and then scroll through them if I keep hitting it, but anyway.

Also, as pointed out in the Clink documentation, the settings in this `.inputrc` file may be used by other software that also uses [readline](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html). If you want these to only affect how Clink (and in turn ConEmu / Cmder) behave you can do something like this:

```
$if clink           # begin clink-only section
TAB: menu-complete
"\e[Z": menu-complete-backward
$endif              # end clink-only section
```